# Unable to display the detail view on selecting a row in TableView with a UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using a Navigation based application.The third view in my flow has a UITabbar added.On clicking one of the tabs a TableView is displayed.On selecting a row of this TableView I wish to display another view.
My code works fine to the point of displaying the different views on clicking the tabs.When I select a row of the TableView nothing is displayed.I use a plist to populate the tableView. I added the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PropertyRegistration *dvController = [[PropertyRegistration alloc]  initWithNibName:@"PropertyRegistration" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    //dvController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil; 
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the third view controller is a UITabBarController which is working fine.  But your root controllers in each tab, are you sure that they are UINavigationControllers?  They (or at least the one containing your table view) need to be.

[image]

If your third view controller is not a UITabBarController, I'd recommend that you change it to be so.  Then your structure would be something like:

UINavigationController: pushes through two UIViewControllers, then a UITabBarController (your third).

UITabBarController contains some view controllers, one or more of which is a UINavigationController.  This navigation controller has a UIViewController as it's root view controller, and has other controllers pushed onto it.

Comment: I am not using the UITabbar Controller. I am just using the UITabbar.

Comment: I'd recommend you use a UITabBarController instead of just a UITabBar.  I edited my answer to explain the suggested structure further.

Comment: Thnks..I shall try implementing it the way you mentioned